# Yammer oauth login from win8 winrt javascript app

Tags: javascript, oauth, windows-runtime, winjs, yammer

I am struggling with logging into Yammer from a windows8 winrt javascript app.
I have tried the suggestions here:
https://developer.yammer.com/authentication/

If I use the yammer login button I get access denied on window.open

If I set an iframe to point to;
https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[:client_id]&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri

This fails as the login page cannot be embedded in an iframe

Have also tried:
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri);
But requires redirect url and not quite sure how to redirect back to my winrt app/not very elegant solution

Is it possible to do the oauth sign in without the yammer login page/dialog?

Comment: +1 nice question m looking for a solution as i have worked in winjs and html but not in yammer will update in a day or two

Answer (score 0):

For those interested I have found a sample app:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Used parts of the Flickr & Facebook examples and can now authenticate.